# Handling QR Code in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, qr-code

I am working on `QR` `Codes` where where i will get some contents with multiple fields (ex. name,address,contact number etc) from `QR` `Code`.

When I tried I am getting response.
But in single string format.

So if I want to separate these contents.

How do I can separate the contents in different fields.

```
response :

VERSION:3.0
N:Patil;Pradumna
FN:Pradumna Patil
ORG:techsanskar
TITLE:iphone
ADR:;;;;;;
TEL;WORK;VOICE:
TEL;CELL:9420256819
TEL;FAX:
EMAIL;WORK;INTERNET:
URL:
BDAY:
END:VCARD
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have string in this format **name,address,contact number**
Like these are seperated by ',' You can use

```
NSArray *items = [theString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSString *name = items[0];
NSString *address = items[1];//etc
```

Comment: it is not separated by any thing .